# Return Json in login_check

Tags: php, json, symfony

im new with symfony and i'd like to return a json when a user make login, but i dont know how.
I'm using a simple form with login_check to authenticate the user in my database, i just want to return this:

```
$response = new JsonResponse('borala', 200,  array(
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
```

Comment: You can do what @Ragdata has suggested but it's a lot of work.  The Symfony security system will redirect after a successful login.  You can put your code in the redirected controller.  The problem is that I'm not sure what you are trying to do makes much sense.

Comment: @Cerad - I assumed he was going for an AJAX login (in which case the redirect needs to be avoided).  [Custom Authentication Listeners](http://www.webtipblog.com/create-authentication-listener-symfony-2/) are also a good option when you need to slip something into the authentication workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because login_check is a 'phantom' route that doesn't actually correspond to a contoller, you'll need to use a Custom Authentication Handler.  Here's how I've done it (simplified):

*The Handler*

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;

class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    protected $router;
    protected $session;

    public function __construct( RouterInterface $router, Session $session )
    {
        $this->router  = $router;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure( Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception )
    {
        if( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() )
        {
            $response = new Response( json_encode( array( 'success' => false, 'message' => $exception->getMessage() ) ) );
            $response->headers->set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );

            return $response;
        }

        $request->getSession()->set( Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception );

        return new RedirectResponse( $this->router->generate('site_login') );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess( Request $request, TokenInterface $token )
    {
        if( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() )
        {
            $response = new Response( json_encode( array( 'success' => true ) ) );
            $response->headers->set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );

            return $response;
        }

        $url = ( $this->session->get('_security.main.target_path') ) ? $this->session->get('_security.main.target_path') : $this->router->generate('home') ;

        return new RedirectResponse( $url );
    }
```

Set the Handler as a Service:

```
security.auth_handler:
    class:      MyNamespace\Service\Security\Listeners\AuthenticationHandler
    public:     false
    arguments:  ['@router','@session']
```

Set the Handler against the Firewall:

```
    site:
        ...
        form_login:
            login_path:             /login
            check_path:             /check_login
            success_handler:        security.auth_handler
            failure_handler:        security.auth_handler
        logout:
            path:                   /logout
            target:                 /
```

Comment: Why the failure handler is the security authentication?? Please to rest in peace dear Sir

Comment: Now instead of `new Response(...)` you can simply use `new JsonResponse(['success'=>false,...])`